# Isnull pegar a proxima condicao SQL

Tags: sql, query

como posso fazer no SQL server 
uma condição se o retorno de um campo for nulo e ele retornar uma outra condição

`ISNULL( CONVERT(CHAR(08),C.PEDS_DAT_FAT,112), d.NFFE_DAT_ENT) BETWEEN '20180501' AND '20180530')`

basicamente é o `C.PEDS_DAT_FAT` ele retorna normal  e se for nulo ele no meu pensamento teria que ir para  o `d.NFFE_DAT_ENT` mais ele não traz o resultado

Comment: Por favor coloque mais informações da query. O `ISNULL` está no `select` ou na `Where`?

Comment: Ola obrigado, ele está no `where`  .

Comment: se `PEDS_DAT_FAT` for null, usar `NFFE_DAT_ENT` ?

Comment: Sim  mais quando faço isso desta maneira que está vem o campo null sem data sendo que  tem registro  na condição de  `Nffe_dat_ent`

Comment: coloca sua query toda, e a estrutura das tabelas. Se possível faça um exemplo no SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você deve checar se o campo é nulo antes da conversão; então ficaria assim:

```
CONVERT(CHAR(08), ISNULL(C.PEDS_DAT_FAT, d.NFFE_DAT_ENT), 112)
BETWEEN '20180501' AND '20180530'
```